# from builtins import bytes # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin ImportError: No module named builtins

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Using python 3.6.0
Windows 10
Docker server version : 18.09.6

Have an issue building docker
Whenever I am building my docker using:

```
docker build --pull -t user/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

I already installed future using: pip install future.

I run into an error:

> ERROR:
>   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2778:1:
>   no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>           File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl",
>   line 61     _fail(result.stderr)
>           File "/rfail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...)))6d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bz
>   Git Configuration Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from builtins import bytes  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin ImportError: No module named builtins
>
> and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR:
>   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2778:1:
>   no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>           File "/r_fail(result.stderr)zel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bz
>   l", lineFile
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl",
>   line 14, in fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...))) Git
>   Configuration Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from builtins import bytes  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin ImportError: No module named builtins
>
> and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR:
>   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2778:1:
>   no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>           File "/r_fail(result.stderr)zel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bz
>   l", lineFile
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl",
>   line 14, in fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...))) Git
>   Configuration Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from builtins import bytes  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin ImportError: No module named builtins
>
> and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR: Analysis of target
>   '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server' failed;
>   build aborted: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>           File "/r_fail(result.stderr)zel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bz
>   l", lineFile
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl",
>   line 14, in fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...))) Git
>   Configuration Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from builtins import bytes  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin ImportError: No module named builtins

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `pip install future` locally? That will not help during your docker build, instead change the `RUN pip` step in the `Dockerfile.devel` file to include `future`:

```
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install \
    grpcio \
    h5py \
    keras_applications \
    keras_preprocessing \
    mock \
    numpy \
    requests \
    future
```

Comment: For other people stumbling across this: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1371